# No match for operator != for '=' operator overload - Binary trees C++

Tags: c++, overloading, binary-tree, operator-keyword

I'm just getting started with binary trees, and have been provided with some code to implement. I have an operator overload function that is declared like:

```
const intBst& operator=(const intBst&);
```

as a public member function. The body for it as follows:

```
const intBst& intBst::operator=(const intBst& otherTree)
{
    if(this != otherTree)
    {
        if(root != nullptr)

            destroy(root);
        if(otherTree.root == nullptr)
            root == nullptr;
        else
            copyTree(root, otherTree.root);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This function is meant to be able to assign the value of one binary tree to another. The error I get at this line `if(this != otherTree)` is `error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'intBst*' and 'const intBst')|`.

I don't understand whats wrong. The code that I have been given is actually meant for template classes, but I am first trying to use this for only **integers** so maybe there's something I have to change in the declaration of the method?

Comment: Note that `if(this != otherTree)` is comparing a pointer to a reference. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: `if (this != otherTree)` this does not make sense. You are comparing a `pointer` with an `object`. Try `if (this != &otherTree)`.

Comment: *I don't understand whats wrong* -- If you're a Java programmer, then it would make sense.  Not so with C++.  In C++, `this` is a pointer, not a reference.

Comment: Additionally, assignment operators are expected to return a mutable reference, and not a constant reference.